# easy to write a script to test whether the network is ever down for the next 24 hours?

Tags: network-programming

is it easy to write a script to test whether the network is ever down for the next 24 or 48 hours?  I can use ssh to connect to a shell and come back 48 hours later to see if it is still connected to see if the network has ever been down, but can i do it programmatically easily?

Comment: You might get more specific help if you can identify what platform, and any constraints on what kind of script. Windows and *nix are different enough to make a general answer difficult.

Comment: Ummm, even if the network went down, the ssh would remain connected.

Comment: Just to clarify, ssh would remain connected only if sshd was configured so that it doesn't send echo packets. Otherwise, it'll detect network down and disconnect you :)

Comment: Went to check (that's sshd, other servers might act differently):
if ClientAliveInterval is 0 you'll remain connected, otherwise not.

Comment: However the client may think it's still connected until there's some activity, unless ServerAliveInterval (in the client's config) is also nonzero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Internet (and your ethernet) is a packet-switched network, which makes the definition of 'down' difficult.

Some things are obvious; for example, if your ethernet card doesn't report a link, then it's down (unless you have redundant connections). But having a link doesn't mean its up.

The basic, 100 mile view of how the Internet works is that your computer splits the data it wants to send into ~1500-byte segments called packets. It then, pretty much blindly, sends them on their way, however your routing table says to. Then that machine repeats the process. Eventually, through many repetitions, it reaches the remote host.

So, you may be tempted to define *up* as *the packet reached its destination*. But, what happens if the packet gets corrupted, e.g., due to faulty hardware or interference? The next router will just discard it. Ok, that's fine, you may well want to consider that down. What if a router on the path is too busy, or the link it needs to be sent on is full? The packet will be dropped. You probably don't want to count that as down.

Packets routinely get lost; higher-level protocols (e.g., TCP) deal with it and retransmit the packet. In fact, TCP uses the packet drop on link full behavior to discover the link bandwidth.

You can monitor packet loss with a tool like ping, as the other answer states.

Answer (score 2):

If your need is more adminstrative in nature, and using existing software is an option, you could try something like monit:

```
http://mmonit.com/monit/
```

Wikipedia has a list of similar software:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems
```

You should consider also whether very short outages need to be detected.  Obviously, a periodic reachability test cannot guarantee detecting outages shorter than the testing interval.

If you only care about whether there was an outage, not how many there were or how long they lasted, you should be able to automate your existing `ssh` technique using `expect` pretty easily.

```
http://expect.nist.gov/
```

Answer (score 1):

Most platforms support a `ping` command that can be used to find out if a network path exists to an IP address somewhere "else". Where, exactly, to check depends on what you are really trying to answer.

If the goal is to discover the reliability of your first hop to your ISP's network, then pinging a router or their DNS regularly might be sufficient.

If your concern is really the connection to a single node (your mention of leaving an `ssh` session open implies this) then just pinging that node is probably the best idea. The `ping` command will usually fail in a way that a script can test if the connection times out.

Regardless, it is probably a good idea to check at a rate no faster than once a minute, and slower than that is probably sufficient.